# Redefinir a prioridade de um registro na tabela

Tags: sql, oracle

preciso fazer um update para reordenar registros em uma tabela em um banco Oracle 9. Esta tabela armazena registros que são solicitações feitas por usuários à TI.
Assim, resumidamente, tenho na tabela os seguintes campos:

```
PK | NOME DEMANDA | PRIORIDADE
------------------------------
1  | DEMANDA 1    | 1
2  | DEMANDA 2    | 2
3  | DEMANDA 3    | 3
4  | DEMANDA 4    | 4
5  | DEMANDA 5    | 5
```

A prioridade é quem determina qual projeto será feito primeiro pela TI.
Por questões de negócio, pode ser necessário alterar a prioridade das demandas.
Neste ponto chegamos ao problema.
Como reordenar as demandas pela prioridade? Por exemplo, eu poderia ter a demanda 4 como mais prioritária, e a tabela ficaria assim:

```
PK | NOME DEMANDA | PRIORIDADE
------------------------------
1  | DEMANDA 4    | 1
2  | DEMANDA 1    | 2
3  | DEMANDA 2    | 3
4  | DEMANDA 3    | 4
5  | DEMANDA 5    | 5
```

Alguma dica?

**UPDATE 1 - Melhor definição do problema**

O problema está no momento de fazer o update. O usuario pode, dentro do sistema, definir a prioridade da demanda. Imagine que ele está editando a demanda numero 4 que tem a prioridade 4. Ele pode alterar a prioridade para 1.
Assim, basicamente o update seria algo como: update tabela set prioridade = 1 where prioridade = 4. Mas nao basta o update, é preciso reordenar todas as outras demandas.

Se eu simplesmente fizer o update eu estou falando que a demanda que tinha prioridade 1 agora tem prioridade 4. O correto seria que a demanda com prioridade 1 mude para a 2. A demanda com prioridade 2, mude para a 3 e etc... até chegar na demanda 4.

O resultado final seria:

```
PK | NOME DEMANDA | PRIORIDADE
------------------------------
1  | DEMANDA 4    | 1
2  | DEMANDA 1    | 2
3  | DEMANDA 2    | 3
4  | DEMANDA 3    | 4
5  | DEMANDA 5    | 5
```

Comment: Não entendi o problema. Não seria só a sua consulta ter um `order by prioridade`??

Comment: Você quer ordenar a exibição pela prioridade, ou você quer alterar as prioridades com alguma outra referência ? Poste um exemplo de como seria o final...

Comment: Opa. Alterei a pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Comment: a prioridade deve ser única então

Comment: supondo
tabela (PK,DEMANDA,PRIORIDADE)
criar uma procedure do tipo altera_demanda (pdemanda,ppriode,pprioate) , 
faz um update da demanda para pprioate e depois um cursor alterando toda
as demenadas diferentes de pdemanda e maiores que pprioate somando 1
à prioridade , estou meio enrolado aqui para escrever a SP mas vai a ideia básica
as apps chamariam esta sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você não tiver uma `UNIQUE` na coluna de prioridade, pode fazer com dois comandos de update, porém terá que testar antes de está aumentando ou diminuindo a prioridade do registro:

> **Se está Diminuindo a prioridade da demanda:**

```
--vamos alterar a demanda 4, para prioridade 1:
--1 é a nova prioridade, 4 é a prioridade anterior
update demandas set prioridade = prioridade + 1 where prioridade >= 1 and prioridade < 4;

--altera a prioridade que você quer:
update demandas set prioridade = 1 where pk = 4;
```

> **Se está Aumentando a prioridade da demanda:**

```
--agora alterando a demanda 5 para prioridade 6:
--6 é a nova prioridade, 4 é a prioridade anterior (era 3 e foi alterada no sql anterior)
update demandas set prioridade = prioridade - 1 where prioridade > 4 and prioridade <= 6;

--altera a prioridade que você quer:
update demandas set prioridade = 6 where pk = 5;
```

> Dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Resultado (1º Update):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Resultado (2º Update):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b503/6)

> Caso você tenha a `UNIQUE`, faça um update na demanda (antes do update que coloquei) que será alterada jogando um valor que não exista na tabela. Nesse caso, você utilizaria 3 updates.

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou certinho.